# Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation for date between dates matching

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am new to Spring Data MongoDB and mongodb.
How can I get the all offline entries of an document with an aggregation (Spring Data MongoDB)?

If an entry is online, the fields onlineFrom and onlineTo are filled with the start and the end date.
The currentDate is java's 'new Date();'.
If the entry hasn't been online, then the onlineTo and onlineFrom fields doesn't exist (which means that it is offline).

Example entries:

```
{name:'Foo'}, //offline
{name:'Bar', onlineFrom:'aStartDate', onlineTo:'aEndDate'} //online if currentDate between, otherwise offline
```

I tried many criterias, like

```
Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("onlineFrom").gt(currentDate).and("onlineTo").lt(currentDate)
                    .orOperator(Criteria.where("onlineFrom").exists(false).and("onlineTo").exists(false)))
```

without success.

EDIT:

I solved it this way:

```
Aggregation.match(new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where("onlineFrom").exists(false),
                    Criteria.where("onlineTo").exists(false),
                    Criteria.where("onlineFrom").gt(currentDate).and("onlineTo").lt(currentDate)))
```

Comment: How are you saving the date? Probably not working because the date formats in db and the one in query is different. Easiest way do date comparison is to save milli seconds in database.

Comment: I thought Spring Data takes care of the date. The class which Spring Data uses is using java.util.Date type for the field. This Date is saved as an ISODate('...') in the MongoDB.